# Modify appointment in Self-Service Scheduling Flow

Tags: fsl, bookappointment

By following this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_appointment_assistant_sss_new_appointments.htm&type=5) I scheduled an appoinment for a contact using Self-Service Scheduling Flow.

But I am not able to cancel the appointment or modify the appointment. In the same article there is no explanation for that.

If I am not able to modify or cancel an appointment then I must not do POC on this , so just want to whther its possible or not using that flow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this functionality is possible. The details and how to set this up are available here: [Set Up Appointment Assistant Self-Service Scheduling For Existing Appointments](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_appointment_assistant_sss_existing_appointments_parent.htm&type=5)

Comment: Actually I am not using self service scheduling component, I am just using self service scheduling flow. And even thought as per article I diabled this but even I am not able to see the edit and cancel option https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_appointment_assistant_sss_enable_cancel.htm&type=5

Answer (score -3):

As per the out of the box process of Appointment Assistant, it is assumed that the customer would not want to reschedule the appointment when they schedule the first time (using self service scheduling flow).

However, a few days before or on day the actual appointment date, you can send out a request to the customer to confirm the appointment time (using the Self-Service Scheduling component on community page) via an SMS / email. You can allow the customer to confirm, reschedule or cancel using this component. This serves the purpose of giving the customer the power to reschedule the appointment right before the actual appointment date.

Hope this helps you to complete your POC!

Comment: Based on my reading of the question, this doesn't seem to be an answer to the question being asked.